# Is it possible to read infinity or NaN values using input streams?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

I have some input to be read by a input filestream (for example):

`-365.269511 -0.356123 -Inf 0.000000`

When I use `std::ifstream mystream;` to read from the file to some

`double d1 = -1, d2 = -1, d3 = -1, d4 = -1;`

(assume `mystream` has already been opened and the file is valid),

`mystream >> d1 >> d2 >> d3 >> d4;`

`mystream` is in the fail state. I would expect

`std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << " " << d3 << " " << d4 << std::endl;`

to output

`-365.269511 -0.356123 -1 -1`. I would want it to output `-365.269511 -0.356123 -Inf 0` instead.

This set of data was output using C++ streams. Why can't I do the reverse process (read in my output)? How can I get the functionality I seek?

From MooingDuck:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double myd = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
  cout << myd << '\n';
  cin >> myd;
  cout << cin.good() << ":" << myd << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Input: `inf`

Output:

```
inf
0:inf
```

See also: http://ideone.com/jVvei

Also related to this problem is `NaN` parsing, even though I do not give examples for it.

I added to the accepted answer a complete solution on ideone. It also includes paring for "Inf" and "nan", some possible variations to those keywords that may come from other programs, such as MatLab.

Comment: Can you read them all as strings and just convert?

Comment: Could you make it a full example instead of half prose? Could you show whether infinity is printed at all? use `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`

Comment: Short of parsing the input yourself, I don't think so. The C++ streams are not guaranteed to be reversible

Comment: @0A0D I'd rather not. There are about 20 or so doubles that are being read per line.

Comment: @Drise: So?  What's so hard about writing a function and calling it 20 times?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was thinking a operator>> overload would be more useful.

Comment: @Drise: a `operator>>` overload won't work, since that function is already defined as a member.

Comment: @MooingDuck Fair enough. Then does anyone wish to write the function and provide it as the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** To avoid the use of a wrapper structure around a double, I enclose an `istream` within a wrapper class instead.

Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out how to avoid the ambiguity created by adding another input method for `double`. For the implementation below, I created a wrapper structure around an `istream`, and the wrapper class  implements the input method. The input method determines negativity, then tries to extract a double. If that fails, it starts a parse.

**Edit:** Thanks to sehe for getting me to check for error conditions better.

```
struct double_istream {
    std::istream &in;

    double_istream (std::istream &i) : in(i) {}

    double_istream & parse_on_fail (double &x, bool neg);

    double_istream & operator >> (double &x) {
        bool neg = false;
        char c;
        if (!in.good()) return *this;
        while (isspace(c = in.peek())) in.get();
        if (c == '-') { neg = true; }
        in >> x;
        if (! in.fail()) return *this;
        return parse_on_fail(x, neg);
    }
};
```

The parsing routine was a little trickier to implement than I first thought it would be, but I wanted to avoid trying to `putback` an entire string.

```
double_istream &
double_istream::parse_on_fail (double &x, bool neg) {
    const char *exp[] = { "", "inf", "NaN" };
    const char *e = exp[0];
    int l = 0;
    char inf[4];
    char *c = inf;
    if (neg) *c++ = '-';
    in.clear();
    if (!(in >> *c).good()) return *this;
    switch (*c) {
    case 'i': e = exp[l=1]; break;
    case 'N': e = exp[l=2]; break;
    }
    while (*c == *e) {
        if ((e-exp[l]) == 2) break;
        ++e; if (!(in >> *++c).good()) break;
    }
    if (in.good() && *c == *e) {
        switch (l) {
        case 1: x = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(); break;
        case 2: x = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); break;
        }
        if (neg) x = -x;
        return *this;
    } else if (!in.good()) {
        if (!in.fail()) return *this;
        in.clear(); --c;
    }
    do { in.putback(*c); } while (c-- != inf);
    in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return *this;
}
```

One difference in behavior this routine will have over the the default `double` input is that the `-` character is not consumed if the input was, for example `"-inp"`. On failure, `"-inp"` will still be in the stream for `double_istream`, but for a regular `istream` only `"inp"` will be left in the the stream.

```
std::istringstream iss("1.0 -NaN inf -inf NaN 1.2");
double_istream in(iss);
double u, v, w, x, y, z;
in >> u >> v >> w >> x >> y >> z;
std::cout << u << " " << v << " " << w << " "
          << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
```

The output of the above snippet on my system is:

```
1 nan inf -inf nan 1.2
```

**Edit:** Adding a "iomanip" like helper class. A `double_imanip` object will act like a toggle when it appears more than once in the `>>` chain.

```
struct double_imanip {
    mutable std::istream *in;
    const double_imanip & operator >> (double &x) const {
        double_istream(*in) >> x;
        return *this;
    }
    std::istream & operator >> (const double_imanip &) const {
        return *in;
    }
};

const double_imanip &
operator >> (std::istream &in, const double_imanip &dm) {
    dm.in = &in;
    return dm;
}
```

And then the following code to try it out:

```
std::istringstream iss("1.0 -NaN inf -inf NaN 1.2 inf");
double u, v, w, x, y, z, fail_double;
std::string fail_string;
iss >> double_imanip()
    >> u >> v >> w >> x >> y >> z
    >> double_imanip()
    >> fail_double;
std::cout << u << " " << v << " " << w << " "
          << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
if (iss.fail()) {
    iss.clear();
    iss >> fail_string;
    std::cout << fail_string << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "TEST FAILED" << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
1 nan inf -inf nan 1.2
inf
```

**Edit from Drise:** I made a few edits to accept variations such as Inf and nan that wasn't originally included. I also made it into a compiled demonstration, which can be viewed at http://ideone.com/qIFVo.

Comment: What about `NaN` parsing? I know the question doesn't explicitly ask for it, but it is reasonable to include it due to the close relationship `NaN` has to this problem.

Comment: Very interesting edit. Could you show a (ideone) snippet of it in use?

Comment: @Drise: Snippet included in the answer. Regards

Comment: Ok nifty. Why not make it an iomanip/facet thing while you're at it? That way, you'll be able to mix and match with any iostreams classes

Comment: @sehe: The OP wanted to avoid a lot of modifications to existing code. Any `iomanip` I can think of now would involve injecting the manipulator before every input variable. Do you have a better way? Oh wait, I think I see how to do it.

Comment: @sehe: I could implement everything with `peek`/`get`, but I still have a day job... :-)

Comment: I noticed a bit late that parse_on_fail is only being called in known context (I read your code bottom up). In that case, you'd really have to check that the underlying stream is `.good()` before commencing parsing, I think

Comment: @sehe: Thanks, I changed the check against `good`, and only try to take corrective action if the `!good` means `fail`.

Comment: @user315052 Mmmm, I meant you'd need to check that `in.good()` inside `double_istream::operator>>(double&)` before even commencing any parsing

Comment: @user315052 I think it would also be interesting if you were to add an `iomanip` to your answer. Of course, it's not needed based on the question, but I think it would prove fairly useful.

Answer (score 13):

**Update** Provided a simple test case that shows that Boost Spirit is capable to handle all varieties of special values in this area. See below: **Boost Spirit (FTW)**.

### The standard

The only normative information in this area that I've been able to find is in sections 7.19.6.1/7.19.6.2 of the C99 standard.

Sadly, the corresponding sections of the latest C++ standard document (n3337.pdf) doesn't appear to specify support for `infinity`, `inf` and or `NaN` in the same way. (Perhaps I'm missing a footnote that refers to the C99/C11 spec?)

### The library implementors

In 2000, the Apache libstdcxx received [a bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STDCXX-239) stating

> The `num_get<>` facet's `do_get()` members fail to take the special strings `[-]inf[inity]` and `[-]nan` into account. The facet reports an error when it encounters such strings. See 7.19.6.1 and 7.19.6.2 of C99 for a list of allowed strings.

However the subsequent discussion yielded that (at least with *named `locale`-s*) it would actually be illegal for an implementation to parse special values:

> The characters in the lookup table are "0123456789abcdefABCDEF+-".
>   Library issue 221 would amend that to "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-".
>   "N" isn't present in the lookup table, so stage 2 of num_get<>::do_get()
>   is not permitted to read the character sequence "NaN".

### Other resources

[securecoding.cert.org](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=36929727) clearly states that the following 'Compliant Code' is **required** to avoid parsing *infinity* or *NaN*. This implies, that some implementations actually support that - assuming the author ever tested the published code.

```
#include <cmath>

float currentBalance; /* User's cash balance */

void doDeposit() {
  float val;

  std::cin >> val;
  if (std::isinf(val)) {
    // handle infinity error
  }
  if (std::isnan(val)) {
    // handle NaN error
  }
  if (val >= MaxValue - currentBalance) {
    // Handle range error
  }

  currentBalance += val;
}
```

### Boost Spirit (FTW)

The following trivial example has the desired output:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "3.14 -inf +inf NaN -NaN +NaN 42";

    std::vector<double> data;
    std::string::const_iterator f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    bool ok = qi::parse(f,l,qi::double_ % ' ',data);

    for(auto d : data)
        std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3.14
-inf
inf
nan
-nan
nan
42
```

## Summary/TL;DR

I'm inclined to say that C99 specifies the behaviour for *printf/*scanf to include *infinity* and *NaN*. C++11, sadly appears to not specify it (or even prohibit it, in the presence of named locales).

Comment: I'd be more than "inclined to say". The correct part of C99 to look at is §7.20.1.3, which is clear and unambiguous in requiring support for reading "inf" or "infinity" as signifying infinity, and "nan" or "nan<arbitrary>" as signifying a NaN (all of them case insensitive, with `<arbitrary>` basically meaning meaning an arbitrary sequence of input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin your `<arbitrary>` is not arbitrary. It's specified as `NAN(n-char-sequence_opt)`, i.e. the arbitrary part only consists of digits and non-digits, and the parentheses are mandatory. Otherwise e.g. `nanometer` would be read as NaN, which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 9):

Write a function with a signature like this:

```
std::istream & ReadDouble(std::istream & is, double & d);
```

Inside it, you:

1. Read a string from the stream using `operator>>`
2. Try to convert the string to a double using one of various methods. `std::stod`, `boost::lexical_cast`, etc...
3. If the conversion succeeds, set the double and return the stream.
4. If the conversion fails, test the string for equality with "inf" or "INF" or whatever.
5. If the test passes, set the double to infinity and return the stream, else:
6. If the test fails, set the fail bit on the stream and return it.

Comment: `std::stod`? Is that new? I thought the only way was to use a `std::stringstream` and let it format it.

Comment: @Drise: It's new to C++11, yes.  [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: @Drise: I removed the wrapper structure around double in my answer. Regards

Answer (score 4):

Just read your variables into string and parse them. You can't put string into double variables and expect them to be outputted like a string, because if it worked, strings wouldn't be necessary.

Seomthing like:

```
string text;
double d;
while(cin >> text)
{
    if(text == "Inf")       //you could also add it with negative infinity
    {
         d = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    }
    else
    {
        d = atof(text.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: `find` is overkill, and you don't handle negative infinity, but this is a good start.

Comment: Just simple example. I had the same thoughts as you.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is quite old, I would like to contribute the solution that suited my purposes the most. If you consider using Boost, but Boost Spirit seems to be an overkill, you could try using the `boost::math::nonfinite_num_put` and `boost::math::nonfinite_num_get` locale facets [1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/fp_facets.html) like this:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/nonfinite_num_facets.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::locale default_locale;
  std::locale tmp_locale(default_locale,
      new boost::math::nonfinite_num_put<char>());
  std::locale upgraded_locale(default_locale,
      new boost::math::nonfinite_num_get<char>());

  double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

  std::stringstream out_s;
  out_s.imbue(upgraded_locale);
  out_s << inf;
  std::cout << out_s.str() << std::endl;
  std::stringstream in_s(out_s.str());
  in_s.imbue(upgraded_locale);
  double check_inf;
  in_s >> check_inf;
  std::cout << (inf == check_inf ? "nice" : "not nice") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
inf
nice
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom extraction function, since your specific implementation clearly does not handle them correctly.

Comment: Remove the word "extraction" and this answer could be used to answer virtually every SO question ever asked... paraphrased: "You will have to do custom work because your implementation clearly does not work." -- not very helpful :(

Comment: @JesseWebb: The question was "why doesn't this work".  The answer is "because your standard library implementation does not meet the spec".  Additional information is very handy, but not required.

Comment: @MooingDuck "How can I get the functionality I seek?" was also part of the question.