# Questions about Spirit.Qi sequence operator and semantic actions

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have some questions about the sequence operator and semantic actions in Spirit Qi.

I'm trying to define a grammar rule for a floating point number that accepts metric prefixes (u, m, k, M, etc.) as well as the normal exponent form.

```
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> sign = char_("+-") [ _val = _1 ];
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> exp = char_("eE") >> -sign >> +digit;
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> suffix = char_("yzafpnumkKMGTPEZY") [ _val = _1 ];
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> mantissa = ((*digit >> char_('.') >> +digit) | (+digit >> char_('.') >> *digit));
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> unsigned_floating = (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | +digit >> (exp | suffix));
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> floating = -sign >> unsigned_floating;
```

**Question 1:** Why do I have to add a semantic action to the rule `sign` above? Isn't `char` convertible to `std::string`?

**Question 2:** Why does compilation fail when I try to merge the last two rules like this:

```
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> floating = -sign >> (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | +digit >> (exp | suffix));
```

**Question 3:** Let's say I want to let the attribute of `floating` be `double` and write a semantic action to do the conversion from string to double. How can I refer to the entire string matched by the rule from inside the semantic action?

**Question 4:** In the rule `floating` of Question 2, what does the placeholder `_2` refer to and what is its type?

**Edit:**

I guess the last question needs some clarification:

What does the placeholder _2 refer to in the semantic action of the following rule, and what's its type?

```
  rule<Iterator, std::string()> floating = (-sign >> (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | +digit >> (exp | suffix))) [ _2 ];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, blow-by-blow. See below for a out-of-the-box answer.

> **Question 1**: Why do I have to add a semantic action to the rule sign above?
>   Isn't char convertible to std::string?

Erm, no char is not convertible to string. See below for other options.

> **Question 2**: Why does compilation fail when I try to merge the last two rules
>   like this:
>
> ```
> rule<Iterator, std::string()> floating = -sign >> 
>               (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | +digit >> (exp | suffix));
> ```

This is due to the rules for atomic attribute assignment. The parser exposes something like

```
vector2<optional<string>, variant<
      vector2<string, optional<string> >,
      vector2<std::vector<char>, optional<string> > >
```

or similar (see [the documentation for the parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator.html), I typed this in the browser from memory). This is, obviously, not assignable to string. Use `qi::as<>` to coerce atomic assignment. For convenience ***there is `qi::as_string`:

```
floating = qi::as_string [ -sign >> (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | 
                                     +digit >> (exp | suffix)) ]
```

> **Question 3**: Let's say I want to let the attribute of floating be double and
>   write a semantic action to do the conversion from string to double. How can I
>   refer to the entire string matched by the rule from inside the semantic
>   action?

You could use `qi::as_string` again, but the most appropriate would seem to be to use `qi::raw`:

```
floating = qi::raw [ -sign >> (mantissa >> -(exp | suffix) | 
                               +digit >> (exp | suffix)) ] 
       [ _val = parse_float(_1, _2) ];
```

This parser *directive* exposes a pair of source iterators, so you can use it to refer to the exact input sequence matched.

> **Question 4**: In the rule floating of Question 2, what does the placeholder _2
>   refer to and what is its type?

In general, to detect attribute types - that is, when the documentation has you confused or you want to double check your understanding of it - see the answers here:

- [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action/9405265#9405265)

---

### **Out-of-the-box**

Have you looked at using Qi's [builtin `real_parser<>` template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real._code__phrase_role__identifier__realpolicies__phrase___code_), which can be comprehensively customized. It sure looks like you'd want to use that instead of doing custom parsing in your semantic action.

The real_`parser` template with *policies* is both fast and very flexible and robust. See also the recent answer [Is it possible to read infinity or NaN values using input streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420263/is-it-possible-to-read-infinity-or-nan-values-using-input-streams/11420901#11420901).

For models of RealPolicies the following expressions must be valid:

```
Expression                 | Semantics 
===========================+=============================================================================
RP::allow_leading_dot      | Allow leading dot. 
RP::allow_trailing_dot     | Allow trailing dot. 
RP::expect_dot             | Require a dot. 
RP::parse_sign(f, l)       | Parse the prefix sign (e.g. '-'). Return true if successful, otherwise false. 
RP::parse_n(f, l, n)       | Parse the integer at the left of the decimal point. Return true if successful, otherwise false. If successful, place the result into n. 
RP::parse_dot(f, l)        | Parse the decimal point. Return true if successful, otherwise false. 
RP::parse_frac_n(f, l, n)  | Parse the fraction after the decimal point. Return true if successful, otherwise false. If successful, place the result into n. 
RP::parse_exp(f, l)        | Parse the exponent prefix (e.g. 'e'). Return true if successful, otherwise false. 
RP::parse_exp_n(f, l, n)   | Parse the actual exponent. Return true if successful, otherwise false. If successful, place the result into n. 
RP::parse_nan(f, l, n)     | Parse a NaN. Return true if successful, otherwise false. If successful, place the result into n. 
RP::parse_inf(f, l, n)     | Parse an Inf. Return true if successful, otherwise false. If successful, place the result into n
```

See **[the example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real.example)** for a compelling idea of how you'd use it.

Comment: Thanks Seth. That's quite comprehensive!

One question I still have though. You said this type is obviously not assignable to a string:  

   `vector2<optional<string>, variant<
         vector2<string, optional<string> >,
         vector2<std::vector<char>, optional<string> > >`  

So what makes the type:  

   `variant<
         vector2<string, optional<string> >,
         vector2<std::vector<char>, optional<string> >`  

assignable to a string? In other words, what makes two types compatible or incompatible?

Comment: Spirit has _customization points_ for attribute handling (extraction, transformation, assignment) and these are documented [in the advanced section of the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize.html)