# Customizing the full error message for expectation failures (boost::spirit::x3)

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

The `boost::spirit::x3` error handling utilities allow for the user to choose what is shown to the user when an expectation failure occurs. This, however, does not seem to be the case for the line number portion of the message, which is exactly what I'd like to modify. So instead of it printing out `In line 1: etc.` I would like to print some other message in it's place with the same line number info. Anyone know how I could do that, or if it is even modifiable in the first place?

EDIT:

Here's the code straight from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/error_handling.html:

```
struct error_handler
{
    template <typename Iterator, typename Exception, typename Context>
    x3::error_handler_result on_error(
        Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
      , Exception const& x, Context const& context)
    {
        auto& error_handler = x3::get<x3::error_handler_tag>(context).get();
        std::string message = "Error! Expecting: " + x.which() + " here:";
        error_handler(x.where(), message);
        return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
    }
};
```

In addition to the `on_error` function printing out the message, it prints "In line x: ", where x is the line number. I really can't have that, it does not fit in with my project in the slightest.

Comment: You should really provide a sample. I don't think you'd get line number information with standard iterators. If you show me what you mean, I can show you how to customize

Comment: @sehe  According to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/error_handling.html   " x3::error_handler ... is utility class that provides Clang style error reporting which gives you nice reports such as the following: ***In line 16: Error! Expecting: ...***"  And then a bit later "The x3::error_handler handles all the nitty gritty details such as determining the line number and actual column position, and formatting the error message printed. All we have to do is provide the actual error string which we extract from the expectation_failure exception..."

Comment: It looks like it is hardcoded in error_handler<Iterator>::print_file_line() in x3/support/utility/error_reporting.hpp

Comment: @sehe I added a snippet from the boost website, see the edit. Apparently the text is indeed hardcoded in the file as Jerry mentioned. I wonder if there's any elegant way of overriding that without changing the file by hand?

Comment: I've done my error handling without using that, so yes. But I'll compare notes first

Answer (score 1):

Wow. First of all, I did not know all details about that example and `x3::error_handler<>`.

For a good break-down of how to provide error handling/diagnostic messages in X3 from basic principles, see this walk-through: [Spirit X3, Is this error handling approach useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048008/spirit-x3-is-this-error-handling-approach-useful/57067207#57067207)

Traditionally (as in Qi) we would do the position tracking using an iterator adaptor:

- [Get current line in boost spirit grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981589/get-current-line-in-boost-spirit-grammar/46983797#46983797) or [Cross-platform way to get line number of an INI file where given option was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427)
- or even the classic version of this [How to pass the iterator to a function in spirit qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637846/how-to-pass-the-iterator-to-a-function-in-spirit-qi/11658183#11658183)

At first glance it looks like the `position_cache` can be used separately (see eg. [Boost Spirit x3 not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262850/boost-spirit-x3-not-compiling/57298876#57298876)).

However, it turns out that - sadly - `x3::annotate_on_success` conflated the annotation task with error-handling, by assuming that position cache will **always** live inside the error handler. This at once means:

- the error handler is more complicated than strictly required
- this compounds with the fact that `x3::error_handler<>` is not well-suited for inheritance (due to private members and tricky to unambiguously overload  `operator()` while keeping some overloads)
- `x3::annotate_on_success` is simply not available to you unless you at least have a no-op error-handler like (**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4626d1830a4f3884)**)

  ```
    template <typename It> struct dummy_handler_for_annotate_on_success {
       x3::position_cache<std::vector<It> > pos_cache;
       dummy_handler_for_annotate_on_success(It f, It l) : pos_cache(f,l) {}

       template <typename T> void tag(T& ast, It first, It last) {
           return pos_cache.annotate(ast, first, last);
       }
   };
  ```

  and have that present in the context under the `x3::error_handler_tag` for `annotate_on_success` to work.
- On the positive, this **does** have the benefit of not requiring two separate context injections, like:

  ```
   auto const parser
       = x3::with<x3::position_cache_tag>(std::ref(pos_cache)) [
         x3::with<x3::error_handler_tag>(error_handler)
             [ parser::employees ]
         ]
       ;
  ```

So, here's my take on providing a custom error-handler implementation. I simplified it a bit from the built-in version¹.

> One simplification is also an optimization, resting on the assumption that the iterator type is *bidirectional*. If not, I think you'd be better off using `spirit::line_pos_iterator<>` as linked above.

```
template <typename It> class diagnostics_handler {
    x3::position_cache<std::vector<It> > _pos_cache;
    std::ostream& _os;

  public:
    diagnostics_handler(It f, It l, std::ostream& os) : _pos_cache(f, l), _os(os) {}

    void operator()(x3::position_tagged const& ast, std::string const& error_message) const {
        auto where = _pos_cache.position_of(ast);
        operator()(where.begin(), where.end(), error_message);
    }

    void operator()(It err_first, std::string const& error_message) const {
        operator()(err_first, boost::none, error_message);
    }

    void operator()(It err_first, boost::optional<It> err_last, std::string const& error_message) const {
        auto first = _pos_cache.first(),
             last  = _pos_cache.last();

        while (err_first != last && std::isspace(*err_first))
            ++err_first;

        _os << "L:"<< line_number(err_first) << " "
            << error_message << std::endl;

        It cursor = get_line_start(first, err_first);
        print_line(cursor, last);

        auto score = [&](It& it, char fill) -> auto& {
            auto f = _os.fill();
            auto n = std::distance(cursor, it);
            cursor = it;
            return _os << std::setfill(fill) << std::setw(n) << "" << std::setfill(f);
        };
        if (err_last.has_value()) {
            score(err_first, ' ');
            score(*err_last, '~') << " <<-- Here" << std::endl;
        } else {
            score(err_first, '_') << "^_" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template <typename AST> void tag(AST& ast, It first, It last) {
        return _pos_cache.annotate(ast, first, last);
    }

    auto const& get_position_cache() const { return _pos_cache; }

  private:
    static constexpr std::array crlf { '\r', '\n' };

    auto get_line_start(It first, It pos) const {
        return std::find_first_of( // assumed bidir iterators
                std::make_reverse_iterator(pos), std::make_reverse_iterator(first),
                crlf.begin(), crlf.end()
            ).base();
    }

    auto line_number(It i) const {
        return 1 + std::count(_pos_cache.first(), i, '\n');
    }

    void print_line(It f, It l) const {
        std::basic_string s(f, std::find_first_of(f, l, crlf.begin(), crlf.end()));
        _os << boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(s) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Which you can then demo like **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04f56074a37900be)**

```
custom::diagnostics_handler<It> diags(iter, end, std::clog);

auto const parser
    = x3::with<x3::error_handler_tag>(std::ref(diags))
      [ parser::employees ]
    ;

std::vector<ast::employee> ast;
if (phrase_parse(iter, end, parser >> x3::eoi, x3::space, ast)) {
    std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";

    for (auto const& emp : ast) {
        std::cout << "got: " << emp << std::endl;

        diags(emp.who.last_name, "note: that's a nice last name");
        diags(emp.who, "warning: the whole person could be nice?");
    }
} ...
```

Which prints:

```
With custom diagnostics only:
Parsing succeeded
got: (23 (Amanda Stefanski) 1000.99)
L:1 note: that's a nice last name
{ 23, "Amanda", "Stefanski", 1000.99 },
                ~~~~~~~~~~~ <<-- Here
L:1 warning: the whole person could be nice?
{ 23, "Amanda", "Stefanski", 1000.99 },
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <<-- Here
got: (35 (Angie Chilcote) 2000.99)
L:2 note: that's a nice last name
        { 35, "Angie", "Chilcote", 2000.99 }
                       ~~~~~~~~~~ <<-- Here
L:2 warning: the whole person could be nice?
        { 35, "Angie", "Chilcote", 2000.99 }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <<-- Here


 ----- Now with parse error:
L:3 error: expecting: person
 'Amanda', "Stefanski", 1000.99 },
_^_
Parsing failed
```

### Simplifying Down

By breaking the *false coupling* between `annotate_on_success` and `x3::error_handler_tag` context, you could slim it down, a lot:

```
template <typename It> struct diagnostics_handler {
    It _first, _last;
    std::ostream& _os;

    void operator()(It err_first, std::string const& error_message) const {
        size_t line_no = 1;
        auto bol = _first;
        for (auto it = bol; it != err_first; ++it)
            if (*it == '\n') {
                bol = it+1;
                line_no += 1;
            }

        _os << "L:" << line_no
            << ":" << std::distance(bol, err_first)
            << " " << error_message << "\n";
    }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a652ea62c8eda53b)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/position_tagged.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    struct name : std::string, x3::position_tagged {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };
    struct person   : x3::position_tagged { ast::name first_name, last_name; };
    struct employee : x3::position_tagged { int age; person who; double salary; };
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::person, first_name, last_name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::employee, age, who, salary)

namespace custom {
    struct diagnostics_handler_tag;

    template <typename It> struct diagnostics_handler {
        It _first, _last;
        std::ostream& _os;

        void operator()(It err_first, std::string const& error_message) const {
            size_t line_no = 1;
            auto bol = _first;
            for (auto it = bol; it != err_first; ++it)
                if (*it == '\n') {
                    bol = it+1;
                    line_no += 1;
                }

            _os << "L:"<< line_no
                << ":" << std::distance(bol, err_first)
                << " " << error_message << "\n";
        }
    };

} // namespace custom

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

    struct error_handler {
        template <typename It, typename E, typename Ctx>
        x3::error_handler_result on_error(It&, It const&, E const& x, Ctx const& ctx) {
            auto& handler = x3::get<custom::diagnostics_handler_tag>(ctx);
            handler(x.where(), "error: expecting: " + x.which());
            return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
        }
    };

    struct annotate_position {
        template <typename T, typename Iterator, typename Context>
        inline void on_success(const Iterator &first, const Iterator &last, T &ast, const Context &context)
        {
            auto &position_cache = x3::get<annotate_position>(context).get();
            position_cache.annotate(ast, first, last);
        }
    };

    struct quoted_string_class : annotate_position {};
    struct person_class : annotate_position {};
    struct employee_class : error_handler, annotate_position {};

    x3::rule<quoted_string_class, ast::name>     const name = "name";
    x3::rule<person_class,        ast::person>   const person        = "person";
    x3::rule<employee_class,      ast::employee> const employee      = "employee";

    auto const name_def
        = x3::lexeme['"' >> +(x3::char_ - '"') >> '"']
        ;
    auto const person_def
        = name > ',' > name
        ;

    auto const employee_def
        = '{' > x3::int_ > ',' > person > ',' > x3::double_ > '}'
        ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(name, person, employee)

    auto const employees = employee >> *(',' >> employee);
}

void parse(std::string const& input) {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    It iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();
    x3::position_cache<std::vector<It> > pos_cache(iter, end);
    custom::diagnostics_handler<It> diags { iter, end, std::clog };

    auto const parser =
        x3::with<parser::annotate_position>(std::ref(pos_cache)) [
            x3::with<custom::diagnostics_handler_tag>(diags) [
                 parser::employees
            ]
        ];

    std::vector<ast::employee> ast;
    if (phrase_parse(iter, end, parser >> x3::eoi, x3::space, ast)) {
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";

        for (auto const& emp : ast) {
            std::cout << "got: " << emp << std::endl;

            diags(pos_cache.position_of(emp.who.last_name).begin(), "note: that's a nice last name");
            diags(pos_cache.position_of(emp.who).begin(), "warning: the whole person could be nice?");
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        ast.clear();
    }
}

static std::string const
    good_input = R"({ 23, "Amanda", "Stefanski", 1000.99 },
        { 35, "Angie", "Chilcote", 2000.99 }
    )", 
    bad_input = R"(
        { 23,
 'Amanda', "Stefanski", 1000.99 },
    )";

int main() {
    std::cout << "With custom diagnostics only:" << std::endl;
    parse(good_input);

    std::cout << "\n\n ----- Now with parse error:" << std::endl;
    parse(bad_input);
}
```

Prints:

```
With custom diagnostics only:
Parsing succeeded
got: (23 (Amanda Stefanski) 1000.99)
L:1:16 note: that's a nice last name
L:1:6 warning: the whole person could be nice?
got: (35 (Angie Chilcote) 2000.99)
L:2:23 note: that's a nice last name
L:2:14 warning: the whole person could be nice?


 ----- Now with parse error:
L:2:13 error: expecting: person
Parsing failed
```

---

¹ also fixed a bug that causes diagnostics to display wrongly on the first line(?) with `x3::error_handler<>` implementation